# Как найти элемент на странице

Tags: javascript, java, html

Я использую auto hot key, каждый раз когда я перехожу по странице я активирую АХК, чтобы найти элемент.

1. press Ctrl+Shift+I(inspect page)
2. press Ctrl+F
3. type test_id

Данный элемент находиться в теге script

**Как я могу автоматизировать данный процесс, чтобы не активировать АХК каждые 5 секунд? Возможно с помощью javascript?**

Я пробовал этот код, но он не работает:

```
(function() {
    var training = document.getElementsById("test_id")
    if (training[0]) {
      alert("This page is tested");
    }   
})();
```

Comment: Что за задачу то решаете? И почему решаете именно так?

Comment: Потому что страницы на которые я перехожу идентичны, но некоторые из них имееют в коде данную строку с test_id текстом, только таким образом я могу идентифицировать, что страница отличается от остальных.

Comment: это ваша стрнаица? Ваш сайт? Зачем вообще эт овсе делать, что вы делаете?

Comment: в `JS` ведь нет такого метода `document.getElementsById()`? Можете обратиться только к одному `getElementById()`

Comment: @tym32167 Я прохожу анкетирование, которое состоит из специально подобранных вопросов, которые в дальнейшем отправлються на дополнительную обработку и мониторинг. Этьи вопросы как раз имеют данную строку. А остальные вопросы, на них ответ не так уж важен, так как они просто пролистываются. Поэтому я иденцифицирую те вопросы, которые будут переходить на следующий этап, дабы сохранить время на ответы других вопросов.

Comment: @azlov Я уже неделю мучаюсь с этим кодом, не могу найти никакой информации толком, я перепробовал множество вариантов. Этот просто один кажется более подходящим, но до сих пор не могу разобраться..

Comment: Это что то такое, что вы делаете регулярно, каждый день? Если да, то вы можете это автоматизировать, например, используюя Selenium. Также приведите фрагмент того, что вы ищете, у него вобще есть id?

Comment: @tym32167 Каждый день по несколько часов. Я читал о Selenium, но никак не могу разобраться.. У меня установлен selenium IDE в браузере Chrome   
         когда я ввожу в посике элемента test_id - то выделяется вся строка скрипт:             <script type="text/javascript"> const $ws_questions = {"uni_id":640,"test_id":0,"university_model":0,"question_ancor":"12zb3a8se"};
    </script>

Comment: ну то есть вам надо что то вроде `if ($ws_questions.test_id !== undefined) alert('found');`, хотя мне не понятно, как это вам что либо сократит. И вам, скорее всего, даже селениуи не нужен, так как этот скрипт просто часть страницы. Вот если вы намете `ctrl+u` и поглядите исходники страницы, там будет этот скрипт?

Comment: Как и куда вы свой javascript собираетесь добавлять? Чем это быстрее/лучше, чем то, как вы сайчас это делаете?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, будет. Он занимает огромную часть страницы, помимо всего когда, этот скрипт занимает третью часть страницы кода.

Comment: ну так и чем вам этот скрипт вообще поможет, даже если бы он работал?

Comment: @tym32167 В идеале я планривал это сделать автоматизировано. Чтобы каждый раз, после того как я ответил на вопрос, приложение само искало данную строку в коде. Тоесть если ее нет, я отвечаю на вопрос сокращенно. А если приложение находит данную строку в коде, то у меня отображается оповещине, что это тестовый вопрос и я отвечаю на него более обширно.

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы каждый раз проверять в ручную, тестовый ли это вопрос, я бы хотел получать оповещение, что в данный момент нахожусь на тестовом. Я представлял это что-то подобное расширению Page Counter в гугл хроме. Которым я тоже пользуюсь, он считает переходы по страницам, с помощью него я вижу на сколько вопросов я ответил

Comment: Только чтобы данный скрипт дополнительно считывал информацию исходного кода страницы, чтобы отправлять мне оповещение, что вопрос тестовый или нет

Comment: Наверное вам имеет смысл попробовать сделать скрипт для расширения [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)

Comment: @tym32167 Да, Артём, я написал его выше, в самой теме. Но я не могу заставить его работать. Сейчас появилась мысль, что там не хватает строки, которая бы запускала функцию при переходе по странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Устанавливаем [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)
2. Добавляем скрипт

[image: ...]

3. Правим в скрипте нужный шаблон URL и код

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...

    var selector = '#question-header > h1 > a';
    var obj = document.querySelector(selector);
    alert(obj.innerText);
})();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Сохраняем это все

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. ОБновляем страничку и вуяля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае скрипт может выглядеть примерно как

```
if ($ws_questions.test_id !== undefined) alert('.....');
```

Также, так как вам нужен доступ не к элементу, а к переменной, то вам возможно надо будет поиграться с настройками своего скрипта тут

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Попробоавл вписать данный скрипт, что у вас на скриншоте. Расширение при нажатии на иконку указывает, что "Скрипт не запущен". Попробовал ввести тот скрипт, что обозначили вы под скриншотом -  та же самая проблема. Я попробовал установить сторонний скрипт найденный в сети -  тот работает.. Ковыряюсь в настройках

Comment: @NeonNeww я на скрине отметил аттрибут `@match` который указывает к каким страницам можно применять скрипт. Сравните его в ваших скриптах.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/iwJFr0A.png

Comment: @NeonNeww звездочку потеряли `// @match https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/*`

Comment: @NeonNeww добавил код скрипта-примера в ответ.

Comment: Да, действительно. Моя не внимательность! Спасибо Вам большущее!! Неделя поисков и головной боли оказалось одной строкой кода.. Я в шоке. Я безумно благодарен!

Comment: @NeonNeww на здоровье. Если это действительно вам помогло решить вашу проблему, то галочка слева от вопроса :)

Answer (score 0):

Может, вам пригодится расширение http://www.tampermonkey.net/. В нём вы можете создать скрипт, который автоматически будет срабатывать при заходе на определённый сайт (или даже на адрес этого сайта, заданный шаблоном). В этом скрипте вы и сможете использовать что-то вроде:

```js
if (document.getElementById("test_id")) alert("This page is tested");
```

Comment: у автора нет такого элемента, у него `<script type="text/javascript"> const $ws_questions = {"uni_id":640,"test_id":0,"university_model":0,"question_ancor":"12zb3a8se"}; </script>`

Comment: То есть id динамический, каждый раз другой и взять его можно только из кода скрипта? Но в том же скрипте для расширения, наверное, можно сначала найти этот id в тексте скрипта, а потом искать элемент по нему.

Comment: Или, если скрипт страницы присваивает глобальной переменной значение с этим id, эту переменную можно прочитать скриптом расширения.

Comment: Прив вписывании данной строки в tampermonkey скрипт не работает, надо дописать что-то еще? Или просто всавить только эту строку?

Comment: Ну вот вам ниже расписали)